# How do I get rid of the empty rows with no emails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on getting a list of clients with emails.

I have the following "WHERE" clause in SQL:

```
{SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE EMAIL IS NOT NULL OR EMAIL = '' }
```

The issue is that despite of "IS NOT NULL" OR EMAIL='', I keep on getting the Emailcolumn with empty fields. I tried adding an extra space on the ' ', but the issue still persists. See example:
{Emailcolumn:
blah@gmail.com

pedro1@gmail.com

blahblah@gmail.com}

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `email IS NOT NULL OR email = ''` gives you rows where the email is not null plus rows where the email is `''`. Both conditions allow `''`, but you want to *forbid* it. `email IS NOT NULL AND email <> ''`. (The first clause is redundant, because the second also excludes nulls, but you may want it for readability.

Comment: So your table allows both null and the empty string '' for an email? Why is that? What is the different meaning of an email being null and an email being empty in your database? With, say, 1000 rows of which 100 have a null email and 100 have an empty email, `COUNT(email)` would result in 900. Do you really consider this to be 900 emails? Usually you'd have a constraint either forbidding null or ''. (The Oracle DBMS goes as far as to define the empty string and null being the same, which I've learned to appreciate after being rather sceptical in the beginning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
SELECT *
FROM NAME
WHERE EMAIL <> '';
```

This filters out both `NULL`s and empty strings.